# Problem adding class to more lines of a form using jquery clone function

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, clone

I have the following doubt, I am maintaining a form using the php language, it has a method that clones all content, that is, the body of a current row table for each time the user wants to create too many rows, well, this method is written in javascript using jquery. What happens, I added a select to this form and also a function for validating an input field to be required, but the cat's jump is in it, I add a new line, the function copies the current line and creates another one below, right, who does this is the .clone () method, from jquery, and when I edit the line below these changes fall on the line above, my validation function seems to only have an effect on the first line, I'm confused, as I leave and how to solve this bug, I would like a north. Thankful if anyone has a suggestion.

Well, I use another function to make the date field required

So, this function only occurs in the first line, in the cloned lines it does not provide effect, is there a plausible solution to this problem? appreciate

```js
<script type='text/javascript'> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".adicionarItens").click(function() {
        var linha_selecionada = $(this).parents( "tr"); 
        var novalinha = linha_selecionada.clone();
        novalinha.find("input").val("");
        novalinha.find("select").val("NAO");
        novalinha.find("span[id=boton]").parents( "td").remove();
        novalinha.find("span[id=boton2]").parents( "td").remove();
        // Insere conteudo dentro da tag body
        $("#funcionarios tbody:last ").append(novalinha); 
    })
};
</script>
```

```html
<td>
  <select name='atestado_covid_dispensado[]' onchange='verifica(this.value)'>
    <option value='0' (['atestado_covid_dispensado']!='1'? '' :'selected')>Não</option>
    <option value='1' (['atestado_covid_dispensado']=='1'? 'selected' :'')>Sim</option>
  </select>
</td>
<td>
  <input type='text' id='troca_status' size = '12' class='datepicker' name='atestado_covid[]'>
</td>

Below the script that clones

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

this clone method, it adds new lines, but I used the other script to request my field to be validated with required, but it only worked for the first line

this is my method that I want to work for the other cloned lines. but I don't know if this is possible

```js
<script type='text/javascript'> 
function verifica(value){
    var input = document.getElementById("troca_status");
    if(value != 1){
        alert('requerido');
        input.required  = true;
    }else if(value == 1){
        alert('não requerido');
        input.required  = false;
    }
}
</script>
```

Now I'm going to add the page that results from this code on the site, that is, or I add a new line on +, and the changes are only on the first line, it seems that my id "swap_status" only recognizes the first line.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JfS0.png)

Comment: Can you share your code so we can help you debug it?

Comment: Yes I can, it's a very large file, but I can show you how parts that are trying to solve

Comment: Try to reduce it to the smallest possible example so people can read it quicker

Comment: ok I'm going to the point

Comment: You are and friend Dominik, I managed to add the main parts that I am changing

Answer (score 0):

I don't undertand exactly what you are asking, but it seems that the newly added lines are not being validated. From the provided code we can infer that the problem is that the function called "verifica" is using the function called "getElementById" which means that it gets the first element with the given id. If you want to verify all the inputs you'll need to the provide a commom class name to all of the inputs, something like "covid-related-data". After that, get them with "getElementsByClassName" and verify one by one in a loop.

Comment: Okay, I understand what you explained, you can write me an example, even if it's generic, thanks.